# Google Drive api opening localhost links on colab (python)

Tags: python, google-api, google-colaboratory

the drive api opening localhost link
'http://localhost:42667/?state=m5lHFiEGP3Z7je6w5sA7TOb0grkmbp&code=4/sQHVN39t-SlowW6XibgQmCzcPwrQYki4ItOsq55i5A0GYQRUD5pLSVFdYuWKAS95q_ZQvgV2Wi1Jle6Ay4MLWjU&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly'
in new tab when trying to view metadata of drive files on google colaboratory. how to fix this?

```
service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

results = service.files().list(
    q="'1bU93FpusMH2ZFEEqHB19umE3rJv_4QpQ' in parents and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'",
                                      spaces='drive', #2 folder long search for better speed
                                      fields='nextPageToken, files(id, name)'
                                      ).execute()

items = results.get('files', [])
```

instead of getting the folder's names and ids like on local runtime, im getting those weird links and the code is stuck.